# Best approach to read serial data using ESP32

Tags: esp32

In the following scenario:

- Rx Clock and Data lines.
- The Rx baudrate is 614.4 kHz.
- The data has bit stuffing that has to be removed.
  What is the best approach to read the data using an ESP32 microcontroller?

Comment: What protocol bus or data is that? There might be a solution if you told what bus that is and from where it comes from.

Comment: This: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-Level_Data_Link_Control

Comment: Configure a USART peripheral in synchronous mode to receive the raw data and then do the bit un-stuffing in firmware.

Answer (score 0):

I would connect the RX-CLK Signal to a ISR-Pin and write code that samples the input-signals on the rising/falling (as required) edge.

I would then feed the raw bits into a FIFO.

Fetching from the FIFO would return data without "stuffing" ready to use.

Comment: Generating a data receive interrupt with a 600 kHz clock to receive 600 kbps data usually is a bad idea. Have you tested if it works?

Comment: @Justme Nope - did not test it. Running the ESP at 240Mhz with a really smil ISR could however work.